# Passing two lists and three strings to a java class from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, ontology

I have created a java servlet and java class 
im instantiating an object and passing two lists and three strings to that class , but when i call the class method from the created object , the method doesn't execute .

```
Class cls {

public void insertMethod (List<String> x, List<String> y, String a, String b, String  c)  
.......
for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom charPropAssertion = factory.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasChar,Text, x.get(i));

AddAxiom addAxiomChar = new AddAxiom(ontology,charPropAssertion);
manager.applyChange(addAxiomChar);
........
}
```

and creating the instance and calling "insertMethod" from the servlet as shown below :

```
cls o = new cls();
o.insertMethod(stlist, dtlist, stNo, stTitle, stText);
```

when i checked the ontology file i couldn't find the new inputs sent from the servlet.

Comment: Have you put any logging in place ?

Comment: Are you able to print the lists & strings on the servlet?

Answer (score 1):

Things you can try :

- Your `class` has no `access identifier`, make sure it's visible from your `servlet`, try making it `public`.If a class has ‘no modifer’, then it CAN ONLY be accessed from ‘same package’.
- Replace all your `code` in your `method` with a simple `System.out.println("i am called");` and see if that executes or not